# VB.NET - Delete 'Named Range' of Activecell

Tags: excel, vb.net, named-ranges

I'm trying to write a code to using VB.Net to delete the Named Range of the activecell. I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax for this. Can someone please help?

```
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

        xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

        xlApp.ActiveCell.Name.Name.Delete()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Application.ActiveCell property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activecell) returns a Range object.

The [Range.Name property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.name) returns a [Name object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name).

The [Name.Name property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name.name) returns a string.

So, the statement:

```
xlApp.ActiveCell.Name.Name.Delete()
```

is trying to call the nonexistent `Delete` method on a string.

The statement should be:

```
xlApp.ActiveCell.Name.Delete()
```

to call the [Name.Delete method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name.delete).

Comment: Thank you @TnTinMan for helping me with this. Much appreciated.